Camunda 8 Optimize component container remains unhealthy
I am using Camunda 8 self-managed instance deployed by docker compose and recently I have upgraded it to version 8.5, all the components are working just fine except Optimize. Its container remain unhealthy and the logs indicate that Optimize not compatible with the version of elasticsearch that is installed along with the compose installation.
Here are the logs:
Caused by: org.camunda.optimize.service.exceptions.OptimizeRuntimeException:
The database Optimize schema version [3.11.5] doesn't match the current Optimize version [3.13.1].
Please make sure to run the Upgrade first.
    at org.camunda.optimize.service.db.schema.DatabaseMetadataService.lambda$validateMetadata$0(DatabaseMetadataService.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)

And when I downgrade my elasticsearch, other components such as Tasklist and Operate stop working. What should I do?
